# Jest expects a native dependency built for Node, but mine are built for Electron - What can I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, jestjs, grpc

How can I resolve a situation where Jest wants native dependencies built for node, but I build them for Electron (using `npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=2.0.2 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --build-from-source`)

How can I get Jest to use the modules built for `Electron`, or manage both simultaneously?

**Node** `8.11.3`
**Yarn** `1.7.0`
**NPM** `5.6.0`

```js
warning package.json: License should be a valid SPDX license expression
$ jest --no-cache --colors
 FAIL  app/redux/sagas/things/__tests__/database.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
    Expected directory: node-v57-win32-x64-unknown
    Found: [electron-v2.0-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module 'C:\projects\myApp\app\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node' from 'grpc_extension.js'


 > 1 | import firebase from 'firebase';
    | ^
  2 | import '@firebase/storage';
  3 | import ReduxSagaFirebase from 'redux-saga-firebase';
  4 | import validate from 'uuid-validate';

  at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:145:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:37:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/grpc/index.js:30:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/firebase/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/redux/sagas/rsf.js:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/redux/sagas/sagaHelpers.js:19:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/redux/sagas/things/database/general.js:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/redux/sagas/things/database.js:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/redux/sagas/things/__tests__/database.test.js:2:1)
```

Comment: Have you tried running just `npm rebuild` without any arguments after the command you ran to install the electron binaries?

Comment: I have and that works for testing, but I can't run my Electron application in that configuration which makes the testing not very useful at all unfortunately.

Comment: OK, when I try doing that on my own machine, I end up with both binary files. One thing I would suggest trying is removing the `--build-from-source` from your `npm rebuild` command. You don't need it, at least for gRPC. If you have other native dependencies, you can add `--build-from-source=<other-package>`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip. Can I ask, what OS are you using? I'll have to investigate the expected behavior of building two sets of binaries further.

Comment: I tested that on Linux, but I don't think that should make a difference here.

Comment: I figured not, but just for good measure. I assume I've somehow broken something else, so I'll investigate further and update here if I find that in fact I cannot have two sets of binaries. Thanks again!

Comment: @murgatroid99 is your comment that you end up with both binaries only applicable to gRPC? At least with the Sharp module, this isn't the case and doesn't seem to be currently possible.

Comment: In general, I expect that many libraries that use `node-pre-gyp` to distribute binaries have that property, but not necessarily all of them, and many libraries don't use `node-pre-gyp`.

Comment: Thanks very much for weighing in on what makes the difference. There's not any end-user implementable stopgap way to manage these that you know of is there? It seems not based on my searches so far.